# iOS Afnetworking unauthorized (401)

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, unauthorized

I'm used afknetwordking 2.0. Error unauthorized 401. I copy my code and error. Can you help me?, please.I don't undertand that problem

```
NSString *token = [PMUserDefaults getAccessToken];
NSString *finalyToken = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",token ];
DLog(@"LIKESAAAA %@", finalyToken);
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Authorization" forHTTPHeaderField:finalyToken];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];


NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"id": @"contentId"};
[manager POST:@"http://IP/Folder/api/Folder/parameter/content_like/parameter" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Length" = 61;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Fri, 01 Aug 2014 09:57:07 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
    "Www-Authenticate" = Bearer;
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
 NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unauthorized (401)
```

Comment: Do you understand what the error code means?

Answer (score 3):

`401` is status `HTTP Error Unauthorized`.
So you maybe do something wrong in authen step.

Your code maybe fail at

```
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"Authorization" forHTTPHeaderField:finalyToken];
```

It need look like

```
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:finalyToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Try it

Comment: Yes, that line of code looks very suspicious. Very unlikely that a request should have a header field named "finalyToken".

Answer (score 0):

In SWIFT 2.0 for iOS9, use:

```
sessionManager.requestSerializer.setValue("Bearer \(token!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```